# Poisson probability of an event A before event B

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I'm trying to calculate the probability of two poisson processes events happening one before the other, with two different $\lambda$s. The way I see it, I can word it as the probability of event $A$ happening within time $t$ and zero instances of event $B$ happening in the same time $t$.

What i'm confused about though is how to go about writing the probabilities. Specifically, I think what i'm supposed to write is

$P(N(t) < 1)* P(N(t) = 0)$

Where

$P(N(t) < s) = \sum_{i=0}^s e^{-t\lambda}\frac{(t\lambda)^i}{t!}$

I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: **Hint:** the inter arrival time ( aka. wait time until the next event ) in a Poisson process is exponentially distributed.  $\Delta T\sim\mathcal {Exp}(\lambda)$

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with that hint.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that the arrival times in a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ follow an Exponential distribution with mean $1/\lambda$. Since inter-arrival times are independent, and you have two Poisson process, then it sounds like  you are asking for 
$$P(T<S)$$
where $T = X_1+X_2$ is the sum of two waiting times for one process, and $S = Y_1+Y_2$ is the sum of two waiting times for the other process.
Notice that if the respective rates are $\lambda$ and $\mu$, then 
$$T\sim\text{Gamma}(2, \lambda)\quad\text{and}\quad S\sim\text{Gamma}(2,\mu).$$

---

So, you want to compute
$$P(T<S) = \int_0^\infty\int_0^s f_T(t)f_S(s)\,dt\,ds = \int_0^\infty\int_0^s \frac{1}{\Gamma(2)}\lambda^2te^{-\lambda t}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma(2)}\mu^2se^{-\mu s}\,dtds$$
where the joint density is the product of the densities of $T$ and $S$ since they are independent.

---

Afterwards, I encourage you to reverse engineer an answer using the binomial distribution and try to see the connection.

Comment: So since T and S are independent events we could say $P(T<S) = \frac{P(T)}{P(T)+P(S)}$ ?

Comment: Not quite.
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(S<T) & = \lambda_{\lower{0.5ex}S} \lambda_{\lower{0.5ex}T} \int_0^\infty \mathsf e^{-\lambda_{\lower{0.5ex}T} t}\int_0^t \mathsf e^{-\lambda_{\lower{0.5ex}S} s}\operatorname d s\operatorname d t
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\lambda_{\lower{0.5ex}S}}{\lambda_{\lower{0.5ex}S}+\lambda_{\lower{0.5ex}T}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I interpret it as you have to condition on that the first 
event has occurred during the arbitrary time interval $(0,t)$ and that the 
second event only occur after the first one has and at an arbitrary time $t$.

Comment: @Ghazal I updated my answer.

Comment: @Ghazal Graham's answer is true if $S$ and $T$ were dealing with one arrival. It is a very well known result.

Comment: @Ghazal Wait, what do you mean by "two poisson processes events happening one before the other, with two different $\lambda$s"? Do you mean you have two process and two arrivals for each? Or do you mean you have two process and **one** arrival for each? My answer is the answer to the first question, Graham's answer is the answer to the second question. The way you worded the situation is misleading.